# Bash script to create a file from a read line

Tags: shell, file, sh

I'm trying to create a new file to save the results of a function. I'm asking for the name of the file to do it interactive. But then, I don't know how to create a new file with this name to save the results.
The piece of the script that doesn't work is this:

```
if [ -f "$3" ]
then
echo "Give a name for the new file: "
read $arch
changefunction $1 $2 $3 > "${arch}"
```

I have tried  > $arch ; > ${arch} but I suppose I don't know the correct way of write it
Thank you very much!!

Comment: No need - the file will be created automatically. The code should work as it is now.

Answer (score -2):

I corrected here

```
if [ -f "$3" ]
then
echo "Give a name for the new file: "
read arch
changefunction $1 $2 $3 > ${arch}
```